# ASPNET 5 vNext Json Serialization

Tags: json.net, asp.net-core

I'm using the beta8 version of ASPNET vNext and JSON serialization is not working.  I can't see anything that would cause the serialization to fail, but maybe I'm missing some JsonOptions in startup.cs?

My class definition looks like this:

```
public class Bcp
{
    public string businessObjectives{get; set;}
    public string businessOwners{get; set;}
    public BcpCountry country{get;set;}
    public List<BcpPartner> businessPartners{get; set;}
}

public class BcpCountry{
    public string name{get; set;}
    public string code{get; set;}
}

public class BcpPartner{
    public string BusinessPartner{get; set;}
    public string BusinessPartnerRelationship{get; set;}
}
```

If the json payload has a null businessPartners property then everything serializes fine, but if the property has anything (even empty array) then the object is null.

Serializes correctly to the class:

`{
       "businessObjectives":"",
       "businessOwners":"Owner",
       "country":{"name":"Åland Islands","code":"AX"},
       "businessPartners":null
}`

Does not serialize and object is null:

`{
       "businessObjectives":"",
       "businessOwners":"Owner",
       "country":{"name":"Åland Islands","code":"AX"},
       "businessPartners":[{"BusinessPartner":"PARTNER      1","BusinessPartnerRelationship":"rel 1"}]
}`

Here is a simple controller action:

```
 [HttpPost("{id}")]
 public IActionResult Update(string id, [FromBody] Bcp data){
     string error = null;
     _logger.LogInformation("Saving " + id);

     var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
     _logger.LogInformation(json);
 }
```

Comment: Does your actual JSON have the newline in the `"businessPartners"` string that is shown in your question?  Carriage returns and newlines in strings must be escaped, according to [the standard](http://json.org/).

Comment: No.  That's just my poor markdown skills.